# Custom key function in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I want to write a custom key function for a question I saw at Pramp. I am used to using something like:

```
my_list.sort(key = lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]))
```

This time I need a more complicated key function, and I realized that I don't know how to write it.
How can I write such a key function for sorting in Python3? Which value should key function return? What should its input be?

My key function (not working)

```
def key_function(num1, num2):
  if abs(num1) < abs(num2):
    return num1
  if abs(num1) > abs(num2):
    return num2
  if num1 < num2:
    return num1
  if num1 > num2:
    return num2
  if num1 == num2:
    return num1
```

From Pramp:

If two numbers have the same absolute value, sort them according to sign, where the negative numbers come before the positive numbers.

```
input:  arr = [2, -7, -2, -2, 0]
output: [0, -2, -2, 2, -7]
```

Their pseudo code answer:

```
    def compare(a, b):
        if abs(a) < abs(b): return -1
        if abs(a) > abs(b): return 1
        if a < b: return -1
        if a > b: return 1
        return 0

    arr.sort(cmp = compare)
    return arr
```

Comment: Python 3 does not support `cmp` functions directly anymore, but you can use [`functools.cmp_to_key()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) and use their pseudocode directly.

Comment: A key function is not a comparison function.  A key function is only passed _one_ element.  When it's used, python iterates over the entire list and runs the key function for each element.  Then it uses the results of that key function to sort instead.

Comment: Here, I’d just sort by absolute value and use the sign as tie breaker: `lambda v: (abs(v), v >= 0))`. This produces `(2, False)` for -2 and `(2, True)` for 2, and so sorts -2 before 2 but after -1 or 0.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank a lot! If I were to write the key as a separate function (asking just to understand it better), as python iterates the list and runs the key function for each element, would the key function return a boolean? A special data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key function needs to return a tuple with absolute values and a sortable indicator of the sign of the value.

- `abs()` will give the absolute value
- `value >= 0` would do for something to sort by sign; negative values produce `False`, which sorts before `True`.

Translated to a `lambda` that’s:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda v: (abs(v), v >= 0))
```

The key function produces:

```
 2 => (2, True)
-7 => (7, False)
-2 => (2, False)
 0 => (0, True)
```

which Python then uses to sort the list by. Since tuples are compared element by element and the first non-equal value determines their order, that means the `False` / `True` sign flag only is used when the first element is equal, e.g. when comparing `(2, False)` (-2) with `(2, True)` (2).

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, I'd like to point out that overwriting the comparison method on a custom object is another way of customising a sort operation.

If the custom key function becomes too complex to handle, this can be a worthwhile approach.

Citing from the docs of [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering):

> Given a class defining one or more rich comparison ordering methods, this class decorator supplies the rest. This simplifies the effort involved in specifying all of the possible rich comparison operations:
>
> The class must define one of __lt__(), __le__(), __gt__(), or __ge__(). In addition, the class should supply an __eq__() method.
>
> For example:

```py
@total_ordering
class Student:
    def _is_valid_operand(self, other):
        return (hasattr(other, "lastname") and
                hasattr(other, "firstname"))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not self._is_valid_operand(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return ((self.lastname.lower(), self.firstname.lower()) ==
                (other.lastname.lower(), other.firstname.lower()))
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not self._is_valid_operand(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return ((self.lastname.lower(), self.firstname.lower()) <
                (other.lastname.lower(), other.firstname.lower()))
```

Answer (score 0):

THis is the simples way:

arr.sort(key=abs)

Comment: This leaves numbers with the same `abs` value on their relative places and the OP needs them sorted a certain way.